# Regex: Match until first occurrence met

Tags: javascript, regex

What I am trying is to match until first occurrence of `&` met. Right now it is matching only the last occurrence of `&`.

My regular expression is

```
(?!^)(http[^\\]+)\&
```

And I'm trying to match against this text:

> https://www.google.com/url?rct3Dj&sa3Dt&url3Dhttp://business.itbusinessnet.com/article/WorldStage-Supports-Massive-4K-Video-Mapping-at-Adobe-MAX-with-Christie-Boxer-4K-Projectors---4820052&ct3Dga&cd3DCAEYACoTOTEwNTAyMzI0OTkyNzU0OTI0MjIaMTBmYTYxYzBmZDFlN2RlZjpjb206ZW46VVM&usg3DAFQjCNE6oIhIxR6qRMBmLkHOJTKLvamLFg

What I need is:

> http://business.itbusinessnet.com/article/WorldStage-Supports-Massive-4K-Video-Mapping-at-Adobe-MAX-with-Christie-Boxer-4K-Projectors---4820052

[Click for the codebase.](https://regex101.com/r/rfM0sJ/1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the non-greedy mode like this:

```
/(?!^)(http[^\\]+?)&/
//               ^
```

In non-greedy mode (or lazy mode) the match will be as short as possible.

If you want to get rid ot the `&` then just wrap it in a lookahead group so it won't be in the match like this:

```
/(?!^)(http[^\\]+?)(?=&)/
//                 ^^  ^
```

Or you could optimize the regular expression as @apsillers suggested in the comment bellow like this:

```
/(?!^)(http[^\\&]+)/
```

**Note:** `&` is not a special character so you don't need to escape it,

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the last `&`?

Comment: @SamKirklandWA If you don't want to match the final `&`, you can do `/(?!^)(http[^\\&]+)/` instead (i.e., match everything that's not a backslash or ampersand.) In that case, the greedy/lazy issue doesn't matter, because there's nothing after the last group.

Comment: For detailed explanations on regex, everyone should try regex101.com. It is the Swiss knife when it comes to parsing text with regex. It generates code in popular languages as well (JS, Python, PHP, Java..)

Comment: +? instead of {1,} or +, or * Got it! Thank you so much!